# Android RecyclerView content not updating after notifyItemInserted

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've got a RecyclerView that needs to update in real-time when content is received. It successfully shows all the content at first load. When attempting to add a new item dynamically, it makes no difference. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Much appreciated!

**MainActivity:**

```
RecyclerView rvClips;
ClipboardRVAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Clip> clips = new ArrayList<>();

private void SetupRV() {
    adapter = new ClipboardRVAdapter(clips);
    rvClips.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    rvClips.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}

//this method gets called everytime a new item is received. I confirmed that it gets called.
public void OnNewClipReceived(Clip clip) {
    clips.add(0, clip);
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

**Adapter:**

Standard adapter code. Simply shows all the items in the recyclerview.

```
public class ClipboardRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClipboardRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    ArrayList<Clip> clips;

    public ClipboardRVAdapter(ArrayList<Clip> clips) {
        this.clips = clips;
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_clipboard_clip, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Clip clip = clips.get(position);
        holder.tvClipTitle.setText(clip.content);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return clips.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView tvClipTitle;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvClipTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClipTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the code a little bit `clips.add(clip); adapter.notifyItemInserted(clips.size - 1);`?

Comment: I am assuming the `MainActivity` is cut down for brevity. If so do you have either of these two set `rvClips.setHasFixedSize(true)`   OR  `rvClips.setHasStableIds(true)` ?

Comment: @avalerio Yeah I included only the essentials here,. but nah I don't have either of those. Should I?

Comment: @hientp Wouldn't that add the item to the end of the list? I'm also trying to place it at the top

Comment: of course, your should use `notifyItemInserted` but is it work if you using `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: @PJDP no `setHasFixedSize(true)` would be a problem and `setHasStableIds(true)` would be a problem if implemented incorrectly. You have neither so not the issue.

Comment: @Linh tried that too, mate! No luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned 'realtime', I'm guessing this could be a thread issue. Your code seems correct. It could be that the adapter needs to be refreshed in a `runOnUiThread` function. Try this:

```
public void OnNewClipReceived(Clip clip) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           clips.add(0, clip);
           adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need this method in your `RecyclerView` adapter.

```
void addNewClip(Clip clip, int index) {
    this.clips.add(index, clip);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}
```

Adding to clips(MainActivity's) won't make a difference because your adapter has it own `ArrayList` to work with.